# Gnome is not working properly after removing the kde-plasma-desktop

Tags: gnome, ubuntu-gnome

Here is a little background what I did so far. I had a flawless gnome3 working but I wanted to give a try to plasma 5 desktop environment, so I installed it. Damn! it was my horrible mistake. After a few hours of usage, i just scratched my head and felt like it's not for me and gnome is far better than this window look-a-like. Here's everything messed up. I removed it using `sudo apt-get remove --purge kde-plasma-desktop` and also ran `sudo apt-get autoremove` . At first, It seemed to be finished, so I did a quick reboot. Here's the problem started, I have pop-os so after the reboot it took me to the pop-os terminal, in other words gui did not work. I tried `sudo systemctl restart gdm3` and I got my gnome desktop back. Thought, I have fixed it but after a reboot, again it took me to the pop-os or ubuntu terminal.
After trying a few more things I ran `sudo systemctl start gdm3.service` it fixed the problem. A few of the kde applications were still there on the system and moreover, it changed my cursor, fonts, icons.
I ran  `sudo systemctl status gdm3`, just to check the status. It threw the below error:

```
    gdm.service - GNOME Display Manager
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/gdm.service; static)
     Active: active (running) since Fri 2020-12-18 19:43:08 IST; 32min ago
    Process: 1044 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/gdm/generate-config (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Process: 1099 ExecStartPre=/usr/libexec/gdm-wait-for-drm (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 1100 (gdm3)
      Tasks: 3 (limit: 12980)
     Memory: 9.3M
     CGroup: /system.slice/gdm.service
             └─1100 /usr/sbin/gdm3

Dec 18 19:43:05 pop-os systemd[1]: Starting GNOME Display Manager...
Dec 18 19:43:08 pop-os systemd[1]: Started GNOME Display Manager.
Dec 18 19:43:15 pop-os gdm-launch-environment][1112]: pam_unix(gdm-launch-environment:session): session opened for user gdm by (uid=0)
Dec 18 19:44:02 pop-os gdm-password][1695]: pam_unix(gdm-password:auth): Couldn't open /etc/securetty: No such file or directory
Dec 18 19:44:13 pop-os gdm-password][1695]: pam_unix(gdm-password:auth): Couldn't open /etc/securetty: No such file or directory
Dec 18 19:44:13 pop-os gdm-password][1695]: gkr-pam: unable to locate daemon control file
Dec 18 19:44:13 pop-os gdm-password][1695]: gkr-pam: stashed password to try later in open session
Dec 18 19:44:13 pop-os gdm-password][1695]: pam_unix(gdm-password:session): session opened for user smehto by (uid=0)
Dec 18 19:44:57 pop-os gdm3[1100]: Gdm: Child process -1202 was already dead.
```

Again, I tried `sudo systemctl enable gdm3` and it gave me below error:

```
Synchronizing state of gdm3.service with SysV service script with /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install.
Executing: /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install enable gdm3
The unit files have no installation config (WantedBy=, RequiredBy=, Also=,
Alias= settings in the [Install] section, and DefaultInstance= for template
units). This means they are not meant to be enabled using systemctl.
 
Possible reasons for having this kind of units are:
• A unit may be statically enabled by being symlinked from another unit's
  .wants/ or .requires/ directory.
• A unit's purpose may be to act as a helper for some other unit which has
  a requirement dependency on it.
• A unit may be started when needed via activation (socket, path, timer,
  D-Bus, udev, scripted systemctl call, ...).
• In case of template units, the unit is meant to be enabled with some
  instance name specified.
```

I don't know what is going on and what those error logs are referring to.

Answer (score 1):

First, when you install `KDE plasma`, you changed your default display manager to `SDDM` and then you removed it.

Relate this situation like this:---you installed an application and set it as default and then you removed it and now the system doesn't know what to do. That's why when you reboot it opens in the terminal.

The solution is to make gdm3 your default display manager again

Do `sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm3` in the terminal and from the options select `gdm3` to make it your default display manager [for more info](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2020/07/change-default-display-manager-ubuntu-20-04/)

Second, I also had a situation where KDE apps and packages were left behind after `purging`. Sadly I didn't find any simple way to make everything back to normal, but what I did was removing everything I had related to KDE through `Synaptic Package Manager`. Be careful if you decide to do this.

Hope this helps  :))

Comment: Thanks for the response.... You got a point ....now I understood why it was not booting properly ..... But what about those `systemctl status gdm3` and `systemctl enable gdm3.service` error logs ?

Comment: as far as I know ``systemctl status gdm``is telling you about gdm3 status, not any error...and for ``systemctl enable gdm3.service`` see that  ``This means they are not meant to be enabled using systemctl.`` is written on line 5.